# How to add column to df with zero array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to add a new column of zero arrays size 20 x 20 to an existing df.

I tried

```
df['matrix']= np.zeros((20,20))
```

received error

```
ValueError: Length of values (20) does not match length of index (26651)
```

It seems like it is trying to append a single zero matrix to the column as opposed to having each entry in a new column be a zero matrix.

Apologies if I didn't format the question correctly, I am new to this site.

Comment: What do you mean by a column of size 20 x 20? A column has size 1 x num_rows

Comment: Do you want to add 20 more columns with 0s or do you want to add one column that contains a list with 20 0s per each row?

Comment: I mean to add a column which has entries which are 20 x 20 arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas tries to broadcast the numpy array to fit your dataframe in ways that are not helpful in this case.

To avoid this you could make a list of the arrays.

```
df["matrix"] = [np.zeros((20,20)) for _ in df.index]
```

Or use `apply` to get the value you want in each cell

```
df["matrix"] = df.apply(lambda _: np.zeros((20, 20)), axis=1)
```

Comment: Only, the second solution you gave really works. If I use the first solution I get the same instance of zero matrix in each row. They return the same id with id() function and when I change one rows matrix entry it changes all of them. Thanks.

Comment: `[obj]*5` is a notoriously bad way of making a list.  All 5 elements reference the same object,

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single column I would suggest adding a pd.Series with the desired information, such as:

```
df['matrix'] = [[0]*20] * len(df)
```